# how to get the count of rows returned of last executed selected query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have just started with the **PostgreSQL** and created a function that returns a table based on the `select` query with `where` clause and `limit`.

I also want to return the count of all the rows from the function that satisfied the condition without considering the `limit` clause.

Here is the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_notifications(
    search_text character,
    page_no integer,
    count integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(id integer, head character, description text, img_url text, link text, created_on timestamp without time zone) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

     DECLARE
        query text;
        skip_records int = page_no * count;

    BEGIN
        query = concat('SELECT id,head,description,img_url,link,created_on from notifications where head ilike ''%', 
                    search_text,'%''','offset ',skip_records,'limit ',count);
         RETURN QUERY Execute query;

    END;
$BODY$;
```

Here is the call

```
select * from get_notifications('s',0,5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76365/get-row-count-of-last-select-query

Comment: + how could I return from same function

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) to return the count of the entire rowset:

```
select  col1
,       col2
,       count(*) over () as total_rows  -- < Window function
from    YourTable
order by
        col1
limit   10
```

The `over` clause specifies the window for `count` to operate on.  The `over ()` is shorthand for `over (rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)`.

[Working example on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/59893/4/0)